# SQLite.NET Extensions Many To Many, no join table records created

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net, sqlite-net-extensions

I am new to using SQLite.NET and the Extensions.

To my best ability I have followed the guides I've found but no records are being created in the many to many join tables and I've no idea why.

I have a solution NuGet dependency on the SQLiteNetExtensions project.

I have the following tables:

```
[Table("Contact")]
public class Contact
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Participant))]
    public List<Journey> Journeys { get; set; }
}

[Table("Journey")]
public class Journey
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Participant))]
    public List<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Waypoint))]
    public List<Location> Locations { get; set; }
}

[Table("Location")]
public class Location
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    [ManyToMany(typeof(Waypoint))]
    public List<Journey> Journeys{ get; set; }
}

public class Participant
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Contact))]
    public int ContactId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Journey))]
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }
}

public class Waypoint
{
    [ForeignKey(typeof(Location))]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(typeof(Journey))]
    public int JourneyId { get; set; }
}
```

When I build the database I use the following test code:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "xandroid.db3");

var db = new SQLiteConnection(platform, dbPath);

db.DropTable<Location>();
db.DropTable<Waypoint>();
db.DropTable<Contact>();
db.DropTable<Participant>();
db.DropTable<Journey>();

db.CreateTable<Location>();
db.CreateTable<Waypoint>();
db.CreateTable<Contact>();
db.CreateTable<Participant>();
db.CreateTable<Journey>();

Location home = new Location { Name = "Home", Latitude=22.22, Longitude=22.22 };
Location perth = new Location { Name = "Perth", Latitude = 4444.4444, Longitude = 4444.4444 };
db.InsertAll(new List<Location> { home, perth });

Contact beans = new Contact { FirstName = "Beans", Surname = "Connor" };
Contact winston = new Contact { FirstName = "Winston", Surname = "Connor" };
db.InsertAll(new List<Contact> { beans, winston });

Journey travelToPerth = new Journey { Locations = new List<Location> { perth }, Contacts = new List<Contact> { beans, winston }};
Journey returnHome = new Journey { Locations = new List<Location> { home }, Contacts = new List<Contact> { beans, winston}};
db.InsertAll(new List<Journey> { travelToPerth, returnHome } );
```

When I access the data I use the following code:

```
var waypoints = db.Table<Waypoint>();
Console.Out.WriteLine(waypoints.Count() + " recorded waypoints");

var participants = db.Table<Participant>();
Console.Out.WriteLine(participants.Count() + " recorded participants");

var journeys = db.Table<Journey>();
Console.Out.WriteLine(journeys.Count() + " recorded journeys");
```

The output of which is:

```
0 recorded waypoints
0 recorded participants
2 recorded journeys
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting the objects using plain sqlite.net methods, that know nothing about your relationships. To save and load relationships you have to use SQLite-Net Extension methods. Most sqlite-net methods also have a `WithChildren` alternative to save relationships:

```
import SQLiteNetExtensions.Extensions;

db.InsertAllWithChildren(new List<Journey> { travelToPerth, returnHome } );
```

Will insert both elements and insert the required records to `Participant` and `Waypoint` tables to save the relationships.

Note: This still requires `Location` and `Contact` elements to be already inserted in database. To insert objects recursively, take a look at the *Cascade operations* section of the [SQLite-Net Extensions documentation](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions).

Comment: Thanks Guillermo, adding the using statement fixed my issue. I think I may have a secondary issue if you might be able to help. When I try persisting the Journey items (the Contact and Location have already been inserted), I get a somewhat nondescript error "near \"where\": syntax error"; this sounds to me like my classes are creating broken SQL when the extensions try to consume them, meaning I've probably made a mistake. I'm using recursive: true for the final InsertAllWithChildren for the Journeys and all relationships in the tables set CascadeOperations to read, any ideas?

Comment: Recursive flag is not needed if elements are already inserted. Try adding primary keys to intermediate tables. Create a bug in https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions if you think that it's a bug in the library.